# Unable to install Java JDK 8

Tags: java

I downloaded the 64 bit JDK from the oracle site (Win7 64bit) and installed it with the install wizard. The instalation folder went in Program file. When I copy the link for the PATH variable and edit it the way it is shown everywhere, it doesn't work. When I check in CMD "java-version" it always says:

> The java version is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Any ideas what is wrong?

I edited this PATH variable so many times and it never worked.

Comment: How are you checking the PATH, can you include your command in your post?

Comment: What exactly is in your `Program Folders` for Java?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin, this is what i am putting in the PATH with ; and everythign that is explained and still it doesnt work.

Comment: Step by step instructions here [How to Install and
Get Started with Java Programming](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html). Please give us the exact output from step 4.

Comment: @Transcendent I am really sorry but I am quite inexperienced in programming and dont get what u mean? I write in CMD java-version... that`s all I did , because this is what i read and saw on videos.

Comment: @laune op is on **windows**. semi-colon is correct as path separator

Comment: Please take care not to use ` instead of ' on StackOverflow :) It has messed up the formatting of your question.

Comment: @DavidPostill  heres what my PATH looks like:%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin

Comment: And the output from step 4.2?

Comment: @DavidPostill here`s the output:   C:\Users\zarko>java -version
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should type `java -version`, not `java-version`.

Comment: what do u mean? where`s the difference?

Comment: java<space>-version **not** java-verson

Comment: The command is java(empty space)-version, what you seem to type is java-version (which is an unexistant command).

Comment: One **essential** space.

Comment: Spoko you were right. Apparently the space fixed the problem and now it is returning my version of JDK.Thanks a lot  to everyone